# Magento 1 : Add additional product with extra price on product page?

Tags: product, magento-1, custom-options, frontend, product-page

I am working on magento 1.9 community edition website.

I want to add a feature in product page such as additional product at extra cost.

Such as if there is a dress worth 500₹ and a belt option is given at product page so that when clicked on that checkbox the additional value ( already assigned ) is added to final.

Comment: You can use custom option with checkbox and extra fee for that option as well.

Comment: can i be please guided how same can be done ?

Comment: Please do accept the answer if solved your issue.

Answer (score 1):

The feature you mentioned is already present in magento in the form of custom options.

Here is official merchant doc, with step by step procedure to add custom options - https://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/catalog/product-options-custom.html